# After Oh-my-zsh install, how can you reenable direct launch of command with shebang?

Tags: command-history, oh-my-zsh, history-expansion

After installing oh-my-zsh using `!!` and typing entry will expand the last command in a new prompt instead of directly relaunch it. How to configure zsh so it do launch directly the command?

Answer (score 0):

`unsetopt HIST_VERIFY`

[See zsh documentation for more details](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html)